# How to get the month wise records in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table name (**task**), here i want take the **count** like how many registration happend in monthwise ,how how can do this ,

```
id              name                   t_completed_on

1               Kani                   2017-02-03 12:45:18

2               yuvi                   

3               Mahesh                 2017-03-11 12:45:18

4               Rajesh                 

5               Kumar                  2017-03-11 12:45:18
```

> Here i am using this format   **date("Y-m-d h:i:s")**

Bassed on my database this month registration 2.

> Expected results:

This month registration : 2

> I tried like this but i am getting the results 0, but actual results i need 2

```
SELECT count(*) as monthrecord FROM task WHERE MONTH (t_completed_on ) = MONTH( current_date ) -1 AND YEAR( t_completed_on ) = YEAR( current_date )
```

Comment: I think the month criteria should be `MONTH(t_completed_on) = MONTH(current_date )`, not minus one, but that aside, even your current query should be returning something.  Are you sure your data is what you actually posted?  What is the type of the `t_completed_on` column?

Comment: `where t_completed_on between date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-01') and now()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expected results:

> This month registration : 2

```
SELECT count(*) as count
FROM my_table
WHERE t_completed_on > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

Comment: I added an edit to change the less than to a greater than... I wouldn't let me make a 1 character edit, so I removed the first two lines which weren't part of the solution :)

Comment: Thanks @LucasKrupinski